# Search MySQL query in PHP

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to make a search query but I got it wrong

Here is my error that I got:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ': search' at line 1

And here is my code:

```
public function search_cafe($search){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cafe WHERE nama_cafe LIKE :search";
    $query = $this -> pdo -> query($sql);
    $query -> execute(array(':search' => '%'. $search . '%'));
    return $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: pdo's [query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query) will run the sql command, change `query($sql)` to [prepare($sql)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare), then you can execute the query

Comment: @catcon It worked, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this hope this may resolve your issue.

```
public function search_cafe($search){
    $query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM cafe WHERE nama_cafe LIKE ?');
    $query->execute(["%$search%"]);

   while ($results = $query->fetch())
   {
     echo $results['nama_cafe'];
   }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The error indicates a problem with your query. Instead, try this query:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM cafe WHERE nama_cafe LIKE '$search'";`

You can use the `%` wildcard to add flexibility to your search. For example, if my query was 'john' and I wanted my query to pick up 'johnson', I would make my query `$sql = "SELECT * FROM cafe WHERE nama_cafe LIKE '$search%'";` (added a `%` at the end).

Comment: Isn't this what OP is doing now?

Comment: I tried this but no results appeared.

Comment: try using `$sql = "SELECT * FROM cafe WHERE nama_cafe LIKE '%$search%'";`